# executing js scripts with Runtime.RemoteObject model objects in Chrome Devtools Protocol

Tags: webdriver, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

Im working with CDP(Chrome Devtools Protocol) and im getting nodeId's with `DOM.querySelector`. After getting `Runtime.RemoteObject` with `DOM.resolveNode` from nodeId, i want to execute scripts with `Runtime.evaluate` like `elem.click()` in javascript. Can i pass `Runtime.RemoteObject` as an `elem` here?

ex:

```py
chrome: PyChromeDevTools.ChromeInterface
node_id = "<node-id-of-an-element>"
remote_object = chrome.DOM.resolveNode(node_id)['result']

chrome.Runtime.evaluate("arguments[0].click()", remote_object)
```